# Why does View class in Django violate the DRY principle?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Python always uses the DRY approach and also motivates programmers to keep their code DRY. Python also provides support to keep its DRY principle intact. But in the API of Django, we come across a class-based view, **View** which is a superclass of all the views.

But the same **View** class is defined in two different packages.

1. class `django.views.generic.base.View`
2. class `django.views.View`

*Why?*

This architecture violates the python DRY principle.

Answer (score 1):

The base View class is defined in a **single** place [django.views.generic.base.View](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/base.py#L36)

For convenience, `View` is imported in [`django.views.__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/__init__.py) so that it can be imported with a shorter path `from django.views import View`